# How to open a new tab in Angular Dart without bootstrapping the app again

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html, dart-webui

I tried to open a new tab  using  window.open(theUrl, '_blank');   It works but it bootstraps the whole app again.  Is there a way to open a new tab without bootstrapping the app ?

Comment: Could you please share some code for context.

Comment: You probably want to use the router https://angulardart.dev/tutorial/toh-pt5 https://angulardart.dev/guide/router